# Trigger syntax for sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have realized that the syntax for triggers is slightly different for different software. What would be the syntax for the following piece of code in SQL Server 2012?

```
Create trigger before_playercatalogue_update
before update 
on player_catalogue
For each row
Begin
    Insert into player_audit
    set action = 'update',
        playerid = old.playerid
        fname = old.fname,
        datachange = (Now);
End
```

Comment: Is there an issue with the code you provided? Are you getting an error message or assuming there are syntax differences between sql server 2012 and another version?

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642822/how-can-i-do-a-before-updated-trigger-with-sql-server

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is quite different.  It would look like:

```
Create trigger after_playercatalogue_update
on player_catalogue after update
as
Begin
    Insert into player_audit(action, playerid, fname, datachange)
        select 'update', playerid, fname, getdate()
        from inserted;
End;
```

Note some of the changes:

- This is an `after` trigger.  SQL Server doesn't have "before" triggers.
- The `set` clause is not supported for `insert`in SQL Server (or other databases).
- SQL Server does not have "new" and "old".  It uses `inserted`, a view on the records that have changed.

Comment: SQL also doesn't have `for each row` but in this case it doesn't matter, it's functionally the same.