# How do I set an ON UPATE rule in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp, sql-update, azure-sql-database

In Mysql, I have the `ON UPDATE` rule which is helpful when I am trying to auto-catch the time a row was updated.

For example:

```
CREATE TABLE important_action 
(
    myAction VARCHAR(50),
    actionStatus VARCHAR(5),
    `date_modified` timestamp DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
        COMMENT 'Data and time record has been modified.'
)
```

How can I achieve same behavior in SQL Server?

Comment: Use a **set based** `AFTER UPDATE` `TRIGGER`

Comment: ON UPDATE  does not exists in ISO standard SQL language specification. It is a trick of MySQL introduced because there was no trigger in MySQL... And it is a stupid behaviour, because it will runs everytime even it is not necessary... The standard ISO SQL language uses triggers to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Larnu mentioned, use an `AFTER UPDATE` trigger. However, the issue you have is that without a unique identifier on the table, your update may not be as targeted as you want. You can add some kind of unique identifier field.

```
CREATE TABLE important_action (
    [uid] int IDENTITY(1,1),
    myAction VARCHAR(50),
    actionStatus VARCHAR(50),
    [date_modified] datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER important_action_update_date_modified ON important_action
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE important_action 
    SET date_modified = GETDATE()
    FROM important_action as ia
        INNER JOIN inserted i 
            ON i.[uid] = ia.[uid]
    ;
END
GO

INSERT INTO important_action (myAction, actionStatus)
VALUES ('testAction1', 'ts1')
    , ('testAction2', 'ts2')

SELECT * FROM important_action;

UPDATE important_action
SET actionStatus = 'us2'
WHERE myAction = 'testAction2';

SELECT * FROM important_action;
```

Results:
First Select:

| uid | myAction | actionStatus | date_modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | testAction1 | ts1 | 2022-11-02 12:35:45.740 |
| 3 | testAction2 | ts2 | 2022-11-02 12:35:45.740 |

Second Select:

| uid | myAction | actionStatus | date_modified |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | testAction1 | ts1 | 2022-11-02 12:35:45.740 |
| 3 | testAction2 | us2 | 2022-11-02 12:35:45.757 |

Comment: thanks, I am used to MySQL, where the row identifier is built into the trigger. Actually, If I am using it BEFORE UPDATE am I able to modify what is about to be updated?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka: SQL Server doesn't have any `BEFORE UPDATE` triggers ....

Comment: See this question about BEFORE UPDATE triggers in SQL Server: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642822/how-can-i-do-a-before-updated-trigger-with-sql-server