# Can I set the default value with a subquery?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to set the default value for shipment_mst.co_num to be pulled from ssspj_shipment_mst.userfield2 . Everything I have seen, and tried gives me the error 'Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.'

My most recent attempts both giving me and error message.

1.

```
ALTER TABLE shipment_mst
ADD CONSTRAINT dfco_num DEFAULT (SELECT userfield2 FROM ssspj_shipment_mst WEHRE shipment_mst.ref_num = ssspj_shipment_mst.shipment_id);
```

2.

```
ALTER TABLE shipment_mst
ADD co_nom nvarchar(10) NOT NULL default (
SELECT userfield2
FROM ssspj_shipment_mst
JOIN shipment_mst
     ON shipment_mst.ref_num = ssspj_shipment_mst.shipment_id)
```

What I ended up doing is creating the co_num column and doing the below.

```
UPDATE shipment_mst
SET shipment_mst.co_num = ssspj_shipmen_mst.userfield2
FROM ssspj_shipment_mst
JOIN shipment_mst
     ON shipment_mst.ref_num = ssspj_shipment_mst.shipment_id
```

Correct me if I am wrong but the Update query I did, only effected the previous records and will have no effect on the future records. Is there a way to set the default for shipment_mst.co_num ? Or do I have to update the table night/write a sp to do so?

Thanks, I apologize as I am just learning Sql and am self/internet taught.

Comment: you would use a before insert trigger

Comment: You can only use a scalar value, as the error message indicates.
You could, however, have a table with defaults (correlated however you need) which you could include as `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s as stand in defaults at he time you use the data (they wouldn't reside next to the data, but it doesn't sound like you want that anyway).

Comment: @nbk there are no "before" triggers in Tsql

Comment: there are stiöö to many empty good functions, but you can use something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/642822/how-can-i-do-a-before-updated-trigger-with-sql-server